# No image displayed while setting image resource of ImageView while it's invisible or gone

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I have an ImageView that is initialized and programmatically added to a custom view that derives from a LinearLayout. The custom view is referenced in an XML layout.

The image resource is set using SetImageResource, and its **container** view state is initially invisible (I've also tried with gone view state).

After an event occurs, the visibility of the container is set to the visible view state on the main UI thread.

**Expected**

I would expect to see the image displayed correctly once the container visibility is set to visible, but I'm unable to see the image.

**Actual**

If I set the initial view state of the container to invisible, then when the visibility is toggled visible, I see the ImageView taking up the expected width and height (using layout bounds) but with no image visible.

If I set the initial view state of the container to gone, then when the visibility is toggled visible, I don't see the ImageView taking up the expected width and height (using layout bounds) and no image visible.

**Why is the ImageView image not appearing when setting the visibility of the container LinearLayout to visible?**

Below is my custom class (image with two captions displayed below it):

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.Content;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Orientation = Android.Widget.Orientation;

namespace ShrimpleSearch.Components
{
    public class CaptionImageView : LinearLayout
    {
        private static TypedArray ReadStyleAttributes(
            Context context
            , IAttributeSet attributeSet
        ) => context.ObtainStyledAttributes(
            attributeSet
            , Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView
            , 0
            , 0
        );

        private static int GetImageResource(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetResourceId(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_drawableSrc
            , 0
        );

        private static float GetDrawableMarginBottom(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetDimensionPixelSize(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_drawableMarginBottom
            , 0
        );

        private static Color GetPrimaryTextColor(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetColor(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryTextColor
            , Color.Black
        );

        private static string GetPrimaryText(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetString(Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryText);

        private static Typeface GetPrimaryFontFamily(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetFont(Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryTextFontFamily);

        private static float GetPrimaryLetterSpacing(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetFloat(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryLetterSpacing
            , 0f
        );

        private static float GetPrimaryTextSize(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetDimensionPixelSize(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryTextSize
            , 0
        );

        private static float GetPrimaryTextBottomMargin(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetDimensionPixelSize(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryTextBottomMargin
            , 0
        );

        private static Color GetSecondaryTextColor(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetColor(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryTextColor
            , Color.Black
        );

        private static float GetSecondaryLetterSpacing(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetFloat(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryLetterSpacing
            , 0f
        );

        private static float GetSecondaryTextSize(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetDimensionPixelSize(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryTextSize
            , 0
        );

        private static float GetSecondaryTextHorizontalPadding(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetDimensionPixelSize(
            Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryTextHorizontalPadding
            , 0
        );

        private static Typeface GetSecondaryFontFamily(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetFont(Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryTextFontFamily);

        private static string GetSecondaryText(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetString(Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryText);

        private static float GetPrimaryTextLineSpacing(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetFloat(Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_primaryTextLineSpacing, 1f);

        private static float GetSecondaryTextLineSpacing(
            TypedArray styleAttributes
        ) => styleAttributes.GetFloat(Resource.Styleable.CaptionImageView_secondaryTextLineSpacing, 1f);

        private static AppCompatImageView CreateImageView(
            Context context
            , TypedArray styleAttributes
            , IAttributeSet attributeSet
        )
        {
            var layoutParameters = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent
                , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent
            ) {Weight = 1};

            layoutParameters.SetMargins(
                0
                , 0
                , 0
                , (int) GetDrawableMarginBottom(styleAttributes)
            );

            var imageView = new AppCompatImageView(context, attributeSet)
            {
                Id = GenerateViewId(),
                LayoutParameters = layoutParameters
            };

            imageView.SetImageResource(GetImageResource(styleAttributes));

            return imageView;
        }

        private static AppCompatTextView CreatePrimaryCaptionTextView(Context context, TypedArray styleAttributes)
        {
            var layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent
                , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent
            ) {Weight = 0};

            layoutParams.SetMargins(
                0
                , 0
                , 0
                , (int) GetPrimaryTextBottomMargin(styleAttributes)
            );

            var textView = new LetterSpacingTextView(context)
            {
                Id = GenerateViewId(),
                Text = GetPrimaryText(styleAttributes),
                LetterSpacing = GetPrimaryLetterSpacing(styleAttributes),
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                Typeface = GetPrimaryFontFamily(styleAttributes),
                LayoutParameters = layoutParams
            };

            textView.SetLineSpacing(0, GetPrimaryTextLineSpacing(styleAttributes));
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Px, GetPrimaryTextSize(styleAttributes));
            textView.SetTextColor(GetPrimaryTextColor(styleAttributes));

            return textView;
        }

        private static AppCompatTextView CreateSecondaryCaptionTextView(Context context, TypedArray styleAttributes)
        {
            var layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent
                , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent
            ) {Weight = 0};

            var horizontalPadding = (int) GetSecondaryTextHorizontalPadding(styleAttributes);

            layoutParams.SetMargins(
                horizontalPadding
                , 0
                , horizontalPadding
                , 0
            );

            var textView = new LetterSpacingTextView(context)
            {
                Id = GenerateViewId(),
                Text = GetSecondaryText(styleAttributes),
                LetterSpacing = GetSecondaryLetterSpacing(styleAttributes),
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                Typeface = GetSecondaryFontFamily(styleAttributes),
                LayoutParameters = layoutParams
            };

            textView.SetLineSpacing(0, GetSecondaryTextLineSpacing(styleAttributes));
            textView.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Px, GetSecondaryTextSize(styleAttributes));
            textView.SetTextColor(GetSecondaryTextColor(styleAttributes));

            return textView;
        }

        protected CaptionImageView(
            IntPtr javaReference
            , JniHandleOwnership transfer
        ) : base(javaReference, transfer) => Expression.Empty();

        public CaptionImageView(Context context) : base(context) => Expression.Empty();

        public CaptionImageView(
            Context context
            , IAttributeSet attrs
        ) : base(context, attrs) => Init(context, attrs);

        public CaptionImageView(
            Context context
            , IAttributeSet attrs
            , int defStyleAttr
        ) : base(context, attrs,
            defStyleAttr) => Init(context, attrs);

        public CaptionImageView(
            Context context
            , IAttributeSet attrs
            , int defStyleAttr
            , int defStyleRes
        ) : base(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes) => Init(context, attrs);

        private void Init(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        {
            var styleAttributes = ReadStyleAttributes(context, attrs);

            var imageView = CreateImageView(context, styleAttributes, attrs);
            var primaryCaptionTextView = CreatePrimaryCaptionTextView(context, styleAttributes);
            var secondaryCaptionTextView = CreateSecondaryCaptionTextView(context, styleAttributes);

            Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

            AddView(imageView);
            AddView(primaryCaptionTextView);
            AddView(secondaryCaptionTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a basic demo so that we can test with it?